# Heavy movement blur in Kivy app. Possible bug?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Recently I started to work on an old project (which I started on Kivy 1.8.0). I decided to upgrade Kivy to the latest version and migrate the code, when I noticed that every animation on my app was heavily blurred. Without knowing if the problem was some incompatibility between versions, I wrote a small piece of code that should have worked.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


kv = '''
MyScreenManager:
    ScreenA:
    ScreenB:

<ScreenA>:
    name: "A"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .7,0,0,.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        center: root.center
        on_press: root.parent.current = "B"
    Image:
        source: "duck.png"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200,200
        pos_hint: {"center":(.8,.5)} 

<ScreenB>:
    name: "B"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,.7,.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        center: root.center
        on_press: root.parent.current = "A"
'''


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ScreenA(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenB(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

This should create two screens, one blue and one red, both with a button that changes the screen, and one of them with an image. I made two short clips to show what I got. The first is the above piece of code in action, the second is just a RecycleView.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LCAVdRALg4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLlNBoJcv7M

I'm using Kivy v1.11.1 and Python v3.7.7 (but got the same results on 3.5) on a 64-bit Windows 10.
I couldn't find anything related to this problem so far. Any ideas?

Comment: When I run it on my computer, it seems perfectly fine! No issues whatsoever!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a graphics driver issue, although I don't know what component of a Kivy version upgrade would have change to trigger it. Make sure your drivers are up to date.

Comment: Well, it seems that everything is up to date. I tried to change KIVY_GL_BACKEND, but the blur is still there. Sometimes it is persistent, specially using RecycleView, to the point that I can't even recognize the items. Also, resizing the window makes kivy recalculate sizes and positions, and then everything goes back to normal.

Comment: It's definitely something arising from an interaction of your gpu drivers with kivy's use of opengl. I don't know which is at fault. To be clear, the reason resizing the window helps is probably something to do with updating the gl context, not the widget level api.